# How to develop program/website and minimaze DB dependecies using C#.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net

How to develop program/website and minimize DB dependencies using C#.NET?
For example I have made some changes in my DB, after that I must rewrite half a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy it to split your application to a different logical layers abstracting the data storage layer from the business logic and UI.

So a simple example will be to have:

1. Data Layer - your database engine;
2. Data Access Layer - code which will know how to read and manipulate data from the Data Layer;
3. Business Layer - will know how to represent Data Access Layer object within your data domain;
4. Presentation Layer - to display/edit Business Layer objects.

For not very complex domains you can use technologies like [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) or [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) to act as 2-3 layers.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Repository pattern](https://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) and [nhibernate](http://www.nhforge.org/)